# electrical outlet issue

Tags: electrical, receptacle

the outlets in the room on the second floor and the outlets in the room in the basement are both not working and havent been for awhile, the breaker seems fine and theres no gfci outlet that needs to be tampered with. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there really only one breaker for all the outlets in rooms two floors apart? Have you tried measuring voltage with a multimeter or used an outlet miswiring tester?

Comment: If it hasn't been working "in a while" then you don't even know where to start.

Comment: those would not be on same breaker

Comment: You say that, but my previous house had a single circuit that served three rooms on two floors. It was fully rewired in the 90s so I have to assume it was just some strange choices by the electrician. Of course it also had five circuits in the laundry room for some reason.

Comment: "breaker seems fine" and how did you get this test result? does it actually switch the supply or just that the "handle" stays in the "on" position?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the rooms arent on the same breaker switch and the entire breaker panel was checked by an electrician not too long after the outlets start working. there is also no single breaker for the room in the basement but instead theres a breaker for each outlet.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the breaker.

Get and use a multi meter and a non contact voltage detector.  Remove the face plates from the outlets and test with both for no power.  Check the top and bottom of the outlets/receptacles, one half can be on another breaker.

Take pictures of how the wires are connected and then check for problems, loose or broken wires or any burn marks.

Comment: the outlets look good, wires are tightly attached and no burn marks, also the outlets to each room are on separate breakers but they both stopped working at the same time so maybe a common issue.

Comment: @ray  With the meter test the outlets and breakers.  hot/black to neutral/white should read 120v.  hot to ground should read 120v also.  neutral to ground the reading should be 0v.

Comment: i couldnt use a multi-meter to test the outlets as i dont have one and the non contact voltage detector doesnt pick any voltage up on any of the affected outlets

Comment: @ray  Is that reading with the breaker on?  If so then the problem is between the breaker and the outlet.  A multi-meter will help to narrow the problem down.  Pictures of the outlets(showing the the wires connected) and the panel will help also.  You might also have a fried mice problem in the walls.  Breakers seem fine, turn the breakers full off and then on.  A question just stating outlets do not work does not give us much to go with.